# How to know who is the requester in Jpos?

Tags: java, jpos

I have a program using jpos, i want to filter so my server only respond from specific ip or port.

how to know where message come from ? This is my simple code

```
    public class ServerListener implements ISORequestListener {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerListener.class);

    @Override
    public boolean process(ISOSource requester, ISOMsg reqMsg) {

    logger.debug("Heder Destinatnion " +reqMsg.getISOHeader().getDestination());

    logger.debug("Heder Source " +reqMsg.getISOHeader().getSource());
    return false
    }
    }
```

the log only show

Heder Destinatnion = null

Heder Source = null

Answer (score 1):

If your `ISOSource` implementation is actually a channel that extends `BaseChannel` (most channel implementations extend `BaseChannel`), then you can cast your `ISOSource` to `BaseChannel` and get a reference to the underlying socket using `BaseChannel.getSocket()`.

If you are using `QServer` you can configure the allowed hosts using the `allow` property.

And of course, you can use a firewall.